# What is the range of $x,y,z$ when $n$ is a known natural number in: $n=x^5+y^5+z^5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions, natural-numbers

I have the following question:

> What is the range of the sum of three distinct natural numbers to the fifth power than are equal to a known natural number?

Mathematically speaking:

$$n=x^5+y^5+z^5\tag1$$

When $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is known, what is the range where $x\space\wedge\space y\space\wedge\space z\in\mathbb{N}$ can be in when we know that $x\ne y\ne z$?

---

I think that the range should be: $1\le x,y,z\le\left(\left\lceil\sqrt{n}\right\rceil\right)^5$ but I am not sure why that should be true.

Comment: Since $x,y,z$ all three belong to $\mathbb{N}$, the upper bound will be $\lfloor \sqrt[5]{n-33}\rfloor$, provided that $n\ge 276$, otherwise their will be *no solution*. Moreover, there exists integers such that we have *no solution*. For Eg: $n=277$

Comment: You have a typo, there is 5th root.

Comment: @Kumar Where does that upper bound come from, I do not see that?

Comment: Do you agree that the least value of one of the integers is $1$?Since the other integer has to be greater than $1$, then it must be $2$? Therefore, $n=1^5+2^5+\text{Remaining variable of your choice i.e. x or y or z (say x)} \Rightarrow x^5=n-33$. Now, Can you proceed further do see the claimed upper bound?

Comment: Practically I'd say there is no way to no what the specific range for a specific $n$ is as we can't tell off-hand if $n=x^5+y^5+z^5$ has any solutions and if it does what the range will be.  We do know that if $w=\max(x,y,z)$ then $w^5 < n$ so $w < \sqrt[5]n$ and that if $1\le x<y<z; 2\le y< z$ then $z=\sqrt[5]{n - x^5-y^5}< \sqrt[5]{n-1-32}$ as an *absolute* maximum.  But I'm not sure this is practical as it so very seldom will be this high if it exists at all.

Comment: I guess if you want to test if something like $n=75483758492754892758493257843920$ has solutions you only want to test to $z\le 2374491$ ... but in that case, as you will be testing $x,y$ and $z =\sqrt[5]{n-x^5-y^5}$ one by one, it'd make more sense to figure out the range of the *LEAST* value, not the range of the max value..  If $x < y < z$ then $1\le x \le \sqrt[5]{n-2^5-3^5}=\sqrt[5]{n-275}$ so we'd only have to test to  .... well the exact same amount.  For very high numbers  $[\sqrt[5]{n}]=[\sqrt[5]{n-33}]=[\sqrt[5]{n-275}]$...Again, I don't so *practical* answer to  the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is maximal among them, then $y\leq x-1$ and $z\leq x-2$ (or vice versa).

So $$(x-2)^5+(x-1)^5+x^5\geq n\implies 3(x-1)^5\geq n$$

so $$x\geq \sqrt[5]{n\over 3}+1$$ So $$\sqrt[5]{n\over 3}+1\leq x\leq \sqrt[5]{n-33}$$

if $n\geq 107313$.